# What does a process named "error" mean?

Tags: linux, debian

*ps -ax* is showing me this weird process running on a Debian server:

```
 2498 ?        S      0:00 error -n retry -t unix -u -c
```

This appears several times.

Kernel version is 2.6.18.8-xen. Debian Lenny.

Any clue on what this process is?

Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's part of the Postfix MTA as @akramer replied to you.

But, as a tip for your future :) if you ever again wonder if some process is part of another program, use `ps faux`. It formats the output in a tree like format, linking child processes to parent process. Or alternatively you can use command `pstree -ap`.

Answer (score 1):

Check `/proc/$PID` to explore all info about this process. For example, get the full path:

```
ls -l /proc/2498/exe
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a component of the Postfix MTA. http://www.postfix.org/error.8.html